# Viewkey for outgoing transactions

Tags: viewkey, auditing, watch-only-wallet

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTgadb7M47E&t=34m20s) fluffy mentions the possibility of maybe modifying a viewkey in such a way that you can also see outgoing transactions. Does anyone have any more info on what exactly he meant or how it would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently there was a [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/64bui4/modifying_the_viewkey_to_to_see_outgoing/) on Reddit asking almost the same question which generated quite some additional [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/64mvc9/poll_how_much_do_you_care_if_moneros_view_wallet/) (although without much positive outlook). Here's a [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/64bui4/modifying_the_viewkey_to_to_see_outgoing/dg41645/) by me giving an answer to the original question:

> I asked moneromooo about this on IRC, and he said that what's mentioned by u/fluffyponyza in the presentation probably refers to an idea that was discussed on IRC a very long time ago and implemented in moneromooo's [viewkey-R](https://github.com/moneromooo-monero/bitmonero/tree/viewkey-R) branch. The basic idea seems to be to generate the tx pubkey somehow deterministically with some nonce such that a view-only wallet (i.e. an auditor) can recognize outgoing transfers. This approach is however quite problematic and unreliable as the wallet owner needs to follow a specific procedure when creating a tx so that the auditor can see outgoing transfers; i.e. there needs to be trust between the two parties for the scheme to work. As such, the development was abandoned.
>
> Here's the log of IRC on 2017-April-10: [https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/hnmDKpT5U~kJyCHi0NP4BV5M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/hnmDKpT5U%7EkJyCHi0NP4BV5M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=)